# Mirror domain configuration with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How to make few mirror domains for `example.com`?

Users should be browsing in `example.ru/*` or `example.de/*` domains, but all requests should be sent to `example.com/*` (without redirecting)

I will use it to manage different website languages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how your server is setup. If you're using a `NameVirtualHost` for your site, it's easy - you just add the following line:

```
ServerAlias example.ru example.de
```

to the configuration for your virtual host.

If you're not using virtual hosts, you don't need to do anything - apache will serve the same content regardless of what domain name is used to connect to it.

Of course, you also need to make sure that the DNS records for example.ru and example.de point to the same server as example.com.

If you are using SSL for your website, you need to have a certificate with Subject Alternative Names for all domains you are serving.

Comment: Thanks @Jenny! I forgot to tell one very important detail. I'm using DirectAdmin for hosting management in VPS. So there I can't define this...

Comment: I have no idea what DirectAdmin is. I would suggest you ask their support.